# How to find the empirical formula of a compound containing C, H, O?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Problem: A 5.000 g sample of an organic compound containing C, H, and O atoms was combusted and produced 14.26 g CO2 and 3.335 g H2O. Its molar mass is 108.1 g/mol.

```
 Solution:
      Nc = 14.26 g/44.01 g/mol 
         = 0.3240 mol C
      m  = Nc (12.01) 
         = 3.8912 g
      Nh = 3.335 g/18.02 g/mol
         = 0.1851 mol H
      m  = Nh (1.008)
         = 0.1866 g
      Mo = 5.000 g - 3.891 g - 0.1866 g 
         = 0.9224 g
      No = 0.9224 g/16.00 g/mol
         =0.05765 mol O

  C = 0.3240 mol C/0.05765    
    = 5.6 (5)
    = 28 
  H = 0.1851 mol H/0.05765
    = 3.2 (5)
    = 16
  O = 0.05765 mol O/0.5765
    = 1 (5)
    = 5
```

Comment: In finding the empirical formula of the compound, I keep getting C28H16O5 which has a molar mass of approx. 400+ that is not equal to the given molar mass above. I followed the process of finding the empirical formula, but I'm getting the same result. I don't know what else to do. Oh, and I also considered to get the mass percent composition first, but also the same result. I'm guessing that the formula could be either C7H8O (with 108.1 g/mol), I forgot the other one. What should I do?

Comment: 1 mol water contains 2 mol H .Your approach looks otherwise correct.

Comment: Good practice is starting with symbolic algebraic expressions and keeping it this way until all is ready to plug in literal numbers. It helps in focusing on principles, spotting mistakes and improves orientation, Q/A reusability and the permanent value. 

You may find useful  [formatting mathematical/chemical expressions/formulas](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88).

Comment: C7H8 and C28H16 are quite not matching ratios, considering their ratio is given by CO2/H2O ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample contains $0.324$ mol $\ce{C}$ (weighing $3.888$ g) and $0.371$ mole $\ce{H}$. Total mass : $4.259$ g. Out of $5.000$ g, the sample contains still $5.000 - 4.259 = 0.741$ g $\ce{O}$, or $0.741/ 16 = 0.0463$ mole $\ce{O}$. Compared to the $\ce{O}$ atoms, there is nearly $7$ $\ce{C}$ atoms and $8$ $\ce{H}$ atoms. This is $\ce{C7H8O}$.